# Single regex for different string patterns

Tags: java, regex

I have following input strings. And I want to write a single regular expression for all the strings using java.

Input strings : :-

```
 Fig.1 & 2 – hi everyone.

 Figure 2 – i am fine

 Figure 1: how are you

 Fig.5 – where are you
```

These are some patterns find in different set of pdf documents. So i need to write a regular expression to capture all the possible combination of word 'Figure' followed by the description. Second these patterns can appear from the start of the line , in between and multiple compination can exists in the same line.

Thanks

Comment: `I want to write` -- Please go ahead.

Comment: Send us the regex and/or the java code you have written so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
[^)]+\)\s+Fig(?:\.|ure)\s*\d+.+
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/kK9tC9

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern you need for exact matches of those 4 phrases is:

```
(Fig\.1 & 2 – hi everyone\.|Figure 2 – i am fine|Figure 1: how are you|Fig\.5 – where are you)
```

Comment: Is it possible to imagine a more generic regex? What about `Fig.4 - This one too...`?

Comment: I am not sure what the OP is after. You're answer is more appropriate if he wants to match any statement of that format, but not for exact string matches.

Comment: sorry for the wage info .. i was in hurry . I am trying to write a generic regex to capture any combination of the word 'Figure' followed by the description .. These are the all possible combination i found from the document. And the two combination can exist in a same line also .. Thanks

Comment: Have you had any success with @Alex's response? Looks sound if you want to match the whole line.

Comment: Regex provided by @Alex is great but it wont work if two patterns exists in the same line . I even tried putting $ in the end. Fig(?:\.|ure)\s*\d+.+$

Comment: @RohitHaritash What is a *pattern* for you?

Comment: In this context , i looking for a sentence boundary which is describing the properties of an image . So the common stating keyword is combination of term 'Figure' followed by the some string upto end of sentence boundary.

Comment: Do all sentences end with a full stop or line break?

If you know it ends with a full stop, `[^)]+\)\s+Fig(?:\.|ure)\s*\d+.+\.` should do the trick. If it always ends with a new line, or is at the end of a line add `$` or `\n` and to accept both alternatives try `(\n|\.)`